# STATISTIC_NUM_SLOTS in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am looking to understand the statistics collection part of postgreSQL. I was not able to decipher why the variable `STATISTIC_NUM_SLOTS` is initialized to '5'.

Could someone explain what purpose it serves.

Answer (score 0):

The file `pg_statistic.h` defines the macro as 5, see http://doxygen.postgresql.org/pg__statistic_8h.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 7 built-in kinds of statistics that can be gathered on a column (see the STATISTIC_KIND_* defines in `src/include/catalog/pg_statistic.h`).

But which of those 7 kinds apply to a given column depends on the type of the column, and at most 5 of them can exist simultaneously.  So it reserves space for up to 5, as reflected in STATISTIC_NUM_SLOTS.